# Should you pass an instance of service to a model class?

Tags: design, object-oriented, model

Say we have these view model classes. You can imagine there's an entry in the UI for each subtype of `InfoItem`, and each item contains some text and an icon.

```
abstract class InfoItem(text: String, icon: Image)

class Email(..): InfoItem(..) {

    private email: String
}


class Map(..): InfoItem(..) {

    private address: String
}
```

Now, we need to handle click events. When clicking on an item, we should navigate to the appropriate screen. You can imagine that there's a component on its own that provides these routing methods.

```
interface Router {

    fun openEmailScreen(email: String)

    fun openMaps(address: String)
}
```

I can think of two ways to go about this.

First, we could have a separate function/component, that would do the appropriate thing based on the `InfoItem` type. However, in order to do that, we would have to make otherwise private properties of `InfoType`, public. For example:

```
fun route(infoItem: InfoItem) {
    when(infoItem) {
      is Email -> router.openEmailScreen(infoItem.email) <-- email must be public
      is Address -> router.openMaps(infoItem.address) <-- address must be public
    }
}
```

Another approach would be to introduce an abstract function `navigate(router: Router)` to `InfoItem` and have each item implement it separately. This way, each item knows what it needs to do and can keep all the details to itself. However, we now have a direct dependency to `Router`, which feels weird (although I can't explain why).

```
..
class Email(..): InfoItem(..) {

    private email: String

    fun navigate(router: Router) { router.openEmail(email) }
}
..
```

This example might be very simplistic, but I believe this issue applies to broader design as well.

Comment: What methods does InfoItem currently implement, that use these private properties? As your example currently stands, there's no reason to have these unused private properties.

Comment: I would use these private properties to perform the actual routing. Otherwise, I wouldn't need them in this specific example.

Comment: `email must be public` no it doesn't you can make it private with a getter and have a read-only property

Comment: Also, is this Kotlin?

Comment: It's based on Kotlin, yes. True, but still the field would have to be publicly readable, which is not something I may necesserarily want. This is a trivial example, so it's not as important here.

Answer (score 5):

Give your `InfoItem` a generic `onClicked` event. At the place (maybe a factory) where the specific `InfoItem` objects are created (and hence their type is known), assign each of them an appropriate event handler (so your `EmailInfoItem` gets the function `router.openEmailScreen` as event handler, and your `MapInfoItem` the function `router.openMaps`.

Now, when an item is "clicked", simply call the generic `onClicked` event.

Answer (score 0):

No, models are models. To me they should only represent some piece of information, that's all. They shouldn't be the ones in charge of where to navigate to.

Why should a model know there's something like a `Router` anyways?

Besides that seems like a big logic redundancy having each item go like:

*– «ok if I'm clicked I need to call this specific method on the router they gave me»*

and then the `Router` go like:

*– «ok they called this method on me so I need to show this screen»*

You're moving routing logic to the models so that `Router` is more like a `Navigator` to me.

What I'd do is something like this:

```
open class InfoItem(val text: String, val icon: Image) {
    open val value: String? = null
}

class Email(val email: String, text: String, icon: Image) : InfoItem(text, icon) {
    override val value: String
        get() {
            return email
        }
}

class Address(val address: String, text: String, icon: Image) : InfoItem(text, icon) {
    override val value: String
        get() {
            return address
        }
}

interface Router {
    fun route(item: InfoItem)
}
```

Then in the `ViewModel` where you have your nice `router: Router` instance you have:

```
fun onItemClick(item: InfoItem) {
   this.router.route(item)
}
```